# How to iterate a directory without entering into subdirectories

Tags: go

Lets say I have the following directory structure:

```
RootDir
---SubDir1
------SubSubDir
---------file1
---------file2
---SubDir2
---SubDir3
---file3
---file4
```

I want to iterate only over the contents of the `RootDir(SubDir1, Subdir2, Subdir3, file3, file 4)` and check if it is a dir or a file, without entering into the subdirectories, like `filepath.Walk` does.

Is there any way to do this in the `Go` library ?

edit:

```
files, err := os.Open("c:\\Documents")
file, err := files.Readdir(0)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
}

for f := range file {
    fmt.Println(f.IsDir())
}
```

So here I am trying to iterate trough the FileInfo, which is a slice, and check for every file if it is a directory, but I always get this error:

```
f.IsDir undefined (type int has no field or method IsDir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a directory by opening it with `os.Open` and the returned `*os.File` has a `Readdir()` method which gives `os.FileInfo`s for the direct folder content and these `FileInfo` have an `IsDir()` method.

Comment: Do you know why for me, FileInfo is treated like an int ? (type int has no field or method IsDir)

Comment: @vBx try `for _, f := range file`.

Comment: @Alex: thanks, it works now. But I can't seem to understand why it returns pair of values ?

Comment: Take a look at the spec and work through the Go tour and effective Go. It is how a for loop with a range clause work in Go.